# Dissmissing Keyboard without Calling didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, keyboard, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `ViewController` which has textSearchTableView: `UITableView` and searchBar: `UISearchBar`

I added `UITapGestureRecognizer` to dissmis the keyboard

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

// ...

self.tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "DissmissKeyboard")
        self.tap.delegate = self
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.tap)
// ...

}

func DissmissKeyboard()
    {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

I have added this function to prevent breaking (didSelectRowAtIndexPath) function after selecting the cell

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        if touch.view.isDescendantOfView(self.textSearchTableView) {
        return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

But the problem is: when the keyboard is enabled and i want to dissmiss it,

if i click on the textSearchTableView, (didSelectRowAtIndexPath) will run

How can i dissmiss the keyboard if i click on the `tableView` without calling (didSelectRowAtIndexPath) ? and I don't want to break this function as well

I hope that I describe the problem well
Thanks a lot

Comment: In your case its a bad idea to dismiss keyboard if the user clicks anywhere on the screen. Where would the user click? It would have to be one of the rows of the table and hence your problem. I would put a done button on keyboard and attach resiginFirstResponder to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-write your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if (self.searchBar.isFirstResponder())
    {
        self.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    else
    {
        //Do something here
    }
}
```

**Alternatively:** We usually use this approach in tableviews.

```
self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .OnDrag
```

This will dismiss keyboard when a drag begins in the tableview.

Comment: The question explicitly asks how to do that without calling ```didSelectRowAtIndexPath```. How can this be of any help?

Comment: Thank you it worked, but when i dismiss the keyboard the cell gets selected so i added this line to if clause tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true) but it also cell gets seleceted and then deselected

Comment: Please check updated answer and let me know if it helps.

Comment: You can write this line in viewDidLoad.. I hope it makes your UI more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

How about you have your tableview's delegate return nil for

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

As `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` is probably what you want but not what you asked for: dismissing the keyboard is done by sending the first responder `resignFirstResponder`, for sake of answering the actual question.